# How can I update JRE from JDK1.8.0_212 to 12.0.1?

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, jdk

I have already tried over Preferences-Installed JRE and I get information from Eclipse

> Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found

I'm working with Eclipse 4.12.0 on the MacOS Mojave. Installed Java JDK1.8.0 and JDK 12.0.1. 
If I'm going to add libraries from the Java location there is only the file libjli.dylib.

Comment: Are you asking about the JDK or JRE?  Your first sentence mentions the JRE, which of course is NOT the JDK, but the error is specifically talking about the JDK.  Did you install [Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html) or [GA JDK 12](https://jdk.java.net/12/)?

Answer (score 0):

JRE is no longer separately available beyond v. 8, but is part of JDK, available free from the [Java Foundation](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), or as a commercial Oracle product.